# Is there a loadash function to compare two arrays and return true only if all values from arr2 is present in arr1?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have to compare two arrays and return true if only the array 1 contains all values of array 2. What is the suitable loadash function for this?

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let arr2 = [1, 2] 
let arr3 = [1, 5]
```

comparing arr1 with arr2 should return true 
comparing arr1 with arr3 should return false

Comment: Why not use the pure js?

Comment: `arr2.every(i => arr1.includes(i));`... ? Is there any reason for usign lodash here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if an array is subset of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811421/check-if-an-array-is-subset-of-another-array) and [Check if array contains all elements of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53606337)

Comment: Since you have chosen a non-lodash answer, mention of "lodash" in the title and tags seems to be irrelevant and misleading now.

Comment: Sorry i found a solution in the comments section, but there were no direct answer! What should i do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `every`:

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr2 = [1, 2];
let arr3 = [1, 5];

const allElements = (a1, a2) => a2.every(e => a1.includes(e));
console.log(allElements(arr1, arr2));
console.log(allElements(arr1, arr3));
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, you could take a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and compare with [`Set#has`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has).

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4],
    arr2 = [1, 2],
    arr3 = [1, 5],
    base = new Set(arr1);

console.log(arr2.every(Set.prototype.has, base));
console.log(arr3.every(Set.prototype.has, base));
```

Comment: For further completeness, lodash has an `every` prototype as well, so to "completely" answer the question, though irrelevant, you may want to use `_.every`.

Comment: @briosheje, why should i use a function of a frame work, if i have a function which is native implemented in the language?

Comment: I do agree with you and I wouldn't use that either, however, the question is **Is there a loadash function to compare two arrays and return true only if all values from arr2 is present in arr1?** so, it's worth mentioning that lodash has this prototype as well, though I personally would **never** use it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for loadash here just use native JavaScript [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) method with [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) method

```js
function compareArray(arr1, arr2) {
  return arr2.every(v => arr1.includes(v))
}

let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let arr2 = [1, 2]
let arr3 = [1, 5]

console.log(compareArray(arr1, arr2))
console.log(compareArray(arr1, arr3))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let arr2 = [1, 2] 

for(let x of arr2) {
    _.includes(arr1, x) || true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `_.difference`

```js
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let arr2 = [1, 2] 
let arr3 = [1, 5] 


console.log(_.difference(arr2,arr1).length === 0)
console.log(_.difference(arr3,arr1).length === 0)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: @briosheje You are right. I misunderstood. I have not updated the answer

Comment: How does your answer differ from mine?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`_.difference`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#difference) in such way:

```
let arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
let arr2 = [1, 2] 

const b = _.difference(arr2, arr1).length === 0
```