# Find all strings from an array in another array

Tags: javascript

Given an array of strings:

```
const first_array = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
```

and another array of strings:

```
const second_array = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
```

How can I return true if all the strings from `first_array` are present in the `second_array` and false otherwise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Check if an array is subset of another array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811421/check-if-an-array-is-subset-of-another-array)

Comment: If you use Lodash/Underscore, also take a look at [`_.difference`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#difference)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `every()` method to check whether every element is contained in `second_array`:

```
const result = first_array.every(f => second_array.includes(f))
```

An example:

```js
const first_array = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
const second_array = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']

const result = first_array.every(f => second_array.includes(f))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Ooooh, forgot about the `every` method. Very clever

Comment: @BrandonDyer thanks! Yeah, it is very good method!:)

Answer (score 1):

This should be a nice one-liner to solve the problem.

```js
first_array.reduce((ac, e) => ac && second_array.includes(e), true)
```