# How can I obtain a list of IDs from L1 that do not include all the elements from the second array L2?

Tags: javascript

```js
let L1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 2' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 3' },

    { id: 2, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Object 2' },
    
    { id: 3, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Object 3' }  
];

// Second array
let L2 = ['Object 1', 'Object 3'];

let idsWithMissingNames = L1.reduce((result, item) => {
  if (!L2.includes(item.name)) {
      result.push(item.id);
  }
  return result;
}, []);

console.log(idsWithMissingNames);
//expected result is: 2
```

I included my code as well but it doesn't work.

Comment: What is the expected output?Your code seems to be working as described so not sure exactly what is wrong.

Comment: expected result is: 2

Comment: Why is it just 2 and not 1 and 2 like your code returns?

Comment: @epascarello id=1 has both `Object 1` and `Object 3`, which are all the values in L2.

Comment: because id with 1 contains 'Object 1', 'Object 3'.  { id: 1, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 3' },

Comment: Create an object that's keyed by id, and values are an array of all the names for that ID. Then check if each array is a superset of L2.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811421/how-to-check-if-an-array-is-a-subset-of-another-array-in-javascript for checking subsets, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-an-array-of-objects for grouping an array by a property.

Comment: So it has to match all of `L2` to be excluded? So what would happen with `{ id: 4, name: 'Object 1' },` would that match since there is no 'Object 3'??

Comment: yes  it has to match all of L2 to be excluded, id: 4 will be excluded as well because in your case there is no object like { id: 4, name: 'Object 3' }

Comment: That would be great info to add to your question! :)

Comment: sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is an exclusion AND check, you need to do some pre processing to get the data into a format that it is easy to loop over and find the matches. So create an object with arrays that holds the name.

You will loop over this object and look for all the keys that match. If they all match you exclude it.

```js
let L1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 2' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 3' },

    { id: 2, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Object 2' },
    
    { id: 3, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Object 3' }  
];

let L2 = ['Object 1', 'Object 3'];

// combine all of he names into an array so it is easy look up
const groupedNamesById = L1.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj.id] = acc[obj.id] || [];
    acc[obj.id].push(obj.name);
    return acc;
}, {});

// Loop over your groups of ids to find the items that do not have all matches
const nonMatchIds = Object.entries(groupedNamesById).reduce((ids, entry) => {
  // do all of the names exist for this group? If no, add it to the list
  if (!L2.every(name => entry[1].includes(name))) {
    ids.push(entry[0]);
  }
  return ids;
}, []);

// Display your group
console.log(nonMatchIds);
```

Answer (score 0):

Collect counts and filter ones less than L2's length:

```js
let L1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 2' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 3' },

    { id: 2, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Object 2' },
    
    { id: 3, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Object 3' }  
];

// Second array
let L2 = ['Object 1', 'Object 3'];

 
const counts = L1.reduce((r, item) => ((r[item.id] ??= [item.id, 0])[1] += L2.includes(item.name), r), {});
let idsWithMissingNames = Object.values(counts).reduce((r, [id, count]) => (count < L2.length && r.push(+id), r), []);

console.log(idsWithMissingNames);
//expected result is: 2
```

```
` Chrome/117
-------------------------------------------------------
Alexander    1.0x  |  x1000000  229  234  239  241  243
epascarelo   1.8x  |  x1000000  402  409  411  416  452
-------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark `
```

```js
let L1 = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 2' },
    { id: 1, name: 'Object 3' },

    { id: 2, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Object 2' },
    
    { id: 3, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Object 3' },
    
    { id: 4, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Object 2' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Object 3' },

    { id: 5, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Object 2' },
    
    { id: 6, name: 'Object 1' },
    { id: 6, name: 'Object 3' },
];

// Second array
let L2 = ['Object 1', 'Object 3'];


// @benchmark epascarelo
const groupedNamesById = L1.reduce((acc, obj) => {
    acc[obj.id] = acc[obj.id] || [];
    acc[obj.id].push(obj.name);
    return acc;
}, {});

Object.entries(groupedNamesById).reduce((ids, entry) => {
  if (!L2.every(name => entry[1].includes(name))) {
    ids.push(entry[0]);
  }
  return ids;
}, []);


// @benchmark Alexander
const counts = L1.reduce((r, item) => ((r[item.id] ??= [item.id, 0])[1] += L2.includes(item.name), r), {});
Object.values(counts).reduce((r, [id, count]) => (count < L2.length && r.push(+id), r), []);
/*@end*/eval(atob('e2xldCBlPWRvY3VtZW50LmJvZHkucXVlcnlTZWxlY3Rvcigic2NyaXB0Iik7aWYoIWUubWF0Y2hlcygiW2JlbmNobWFya10iKSl7bGV0IHQ9ZG9jdW1lbnQuY3JlYXRlRWxlbWVudCgic2NyaXB0Iik7dC5zcmM9Imh0dHBzOi8vY2RuLmpzZGVsaXZyLm5ldC9naC9zaWxlbnRtYW50cmEvYmVuY2htYXJrL2xvYWRlci5qcyIsdC5kZWZlcj0hMCxkb2N1bWVudC5oZWFkLmFwcGVuZENoaWxkKHQpfX0='));
```